# Adding space around frame using `\newmdtheoremenv`

Tags: mdframed, amsart

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newmdtheoremenv[
  bottomline=true,
  topline=true,
  rightline=true,
  leftline=true]{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
    ndskjasjkdasd
    \begin{definition}
        jhashkdkaldshadklasldjkasd
    \end{definition}
    adklsjadlsjklas
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

How can I add some space between the frame and the text globally? Is there any option for that in `\newmdtheoremenv`? Also it does bother me a bit that the space above Definition is largen than below (maybe thats intended).

Comment: Using a different class (say `article`) the spacings are different (and more what is expected). You can control the skips above and below the frame with `skipabove=10pt` and `skipbelow=10pt` etc. Using `innerbottommargin=10pt` will set the top and bottom margin inside to same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said elsewhere, the best package for this kind of frames is `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colback=white,
  before skip=\topsep,
  after skip=\topsep,
}

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{definition}
\lipsum*[3]
\end{definition}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes indeed, I asked a similar question yesterday where also `tcolorbox` was recommended. Seems that I have to install the latest version.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek With due respect to Marco Daniel, `tcolorbox` is much superior to `mdframed`.